# Windows Azure Powershell 'you MUST specify a certificate'

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Allright, so I'm getting started with Windows Azure Powershell through my MSDN premium account.

I've got a management certificate in my management portal, and I did the Set-Executionpolicy, Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile, Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile and got the message:

```
Setting 'myemailaddress@hotmail.com' as the default and current subscription ... etc
```

Seems to work fine until here. Then I hit Get-AzureSubscription and I get the error message:

```
Get-AzureSubscription : You MUST specify a certificate. Call Set-AzureSubscription and Select-AzureSubscription first.
```

I repeated the steps in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554332.aspx) document a few times, but I can't get it to work. PowerShell is running in Admin mode, Azure Powershell extensions are installed.

Didn't I install the cert by running the Import command?

**EDIT:**
Yes it is, I checked certmgr and it's installed under Personal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same issue.  Just configured it manually with the guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554332.aspx):

Comment: So did I in the end. Thanks.